# Canon MF229DW fails to render certain text

Tags: mac, pdf, printing, fonts, canon-pixma

I'm a mathematician running Mac OS X 10.14.6 and when I print PDF documents such as https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1240.pdf certain letters, like the I in SQI in the abstract, do not show up in the printout. I've updated the firmware to no avail. I wonder if this is some sort of font issue, but it's quite odd to have BMP characters go away entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is pretty common having problem printing PDF.
And usually it is said it can depend on

- the PDF file it self, print from cloud or local.
- The PDF application and fonts.
- Driver printer.

A quick fix is to print as image.
[Adobe Acrobat - Quick fix print pdf image](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/quick-fix-print-pdf-image.html)